# Can not connect to Mongo docker instance via mono client on mac

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have installed Mongo docker image and run it using those commands (mac boot2docker is installed)

```
docker pull mongo
```

and

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo
```

but now I want to connect to it via mongo client running:

```
mongo --port 27017 --host 127.0.0.1
```

but I get this error message:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2015-07-27T14:22:24.088+0300 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-07-27T14:22:24.094+0300 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

It is clear to me that Docker fails to expose the ports  since telnet to 27017 on the localhost fails as well.

What the hack am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using Boot2Docker? Get the IP of that then connect to that not localhost.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried boot2docker ip

Comment: Please provide `docker ps` output.

Comment: 507713c262c5        mongo               "/entrypoint.sh mong   48 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes       27017/tcp           some-mongo1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 problems :

Like h3nrik said you should connect to the boot2docker VMs address. If you don't know it use the following command :

`boot2docker ip`

And your port **isn't open** in the first place.

Your `Docker run` command should look like this :

`docker run -p 27017:27017 --name some-mongo -d mongo`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `127.0.0.1` you should use the boot2docker VMs IP address. Usually `192.168.59.103`. You can verify to which IP you should connect executing `boot2docker ip`.

**Update**: I discovered that you do not export any ports by your containers `run` statement:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo
```

Without any ports exposed you cannot connect, of course. Try to re-connect after running (depending on your requirements you can add more ports according to the [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/)):

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d -p 27017:27017  mongo
```

Comment: Thanks @h3nrik, mongo --host 192.168.59.103 still does not work, I tried it before asking this question. it looks like something related to boot2docker

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. You do not expose ports that you can connect to by your `run` statement.